# Pycharm with IdeaVim occasionally makes the keyboard unresponsive

Tags: pycharm, ideavim

Every so often when using PyCharm Community Edition with IdeaVim in Ubuntu 13.10, the keyboard stops accepting input and I have to restart the IDE.  The cursor still moves when I click different text areas, but I can't type anything even after pressing escape multiple times.  The keyboard works fine outside of the IDE, so I suspect it is an issue with either my use of IdeaVim or IdeaVim itself.

Is there anything I can do to prevent this from happening?

Comment: I can't say I've ever faced this before. Can you provide a few more details about the problem? Perhaps a screen recording?

Comment: In this screen recording I started getting the problem in a project I was working on, so I created a new one and demonstrated the keyboard not working.  I am typing asdf every two seconds or so... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tM8YdRYc8Zk

Comment: Btw, I've upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 and am still getting the same problem

Comment: Do you have time for a hangout? I might be able to help you out.

Comment: This also happens to me with 14.04 and IdeaVim with IntelliJ Ultimate.

Comment: Happens to me as well, on Ubuntu 14.04 x64 using PyCharm Community Edition 3.1.3. If I set "Keyboard input method system" to None on Settings > Language Support and restart Ubuntu it stops happening, but I have issues with other programs (cant input special chars such as á or ó)

Comment: I'm having the Issue with IntelliJ Ultimate on Ubuntu 14.04. The thing is, I'm also developing on windows with the exact same version - and i don't have the issue there.

Comment: Same problem in Android Studio 0.6.1 and some versions before as well

Comment: I'm having the EXACT same problem with both Android Studio and RubyMine. Checked the logs and it doesn't seem to have logged anything (idea.log)

Comment: Same problem with PyCharm and Emacs keybindings on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 91):

You can do `killall -9 ibus-x11` as described in the issue given by Games Brainiac. I just wanted to note that you don't need to restart the IDE, as it should continue to work again... which is nice, undo-history is preserved etc. :)

Comment: Yep, this solution works for me. I am having the same problem as the OP, but with Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Crazy but this is still an issue on Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: I have no idea what ibus is and I've never used PyCharm.  But I just used this answer to fix the same sort of problem with CLion.  :)

Comment: I have the same issue without vim or emacs plugin (in PyCharm 4.5). This hack works for me too.

Comment: this works but then i get into the problem that i can not type quaoter: " or '

Comment: What's the OSX-equivalent answer?

Comment: There was an ibus warning when I turned it on, which I promptly ignored.

Comment: Crazy but this is still an issue on Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 8):

This is very likely a bug. Please vote for this issue -> http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-759

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problems, i reported it and still do not know of a fix for it. I noticed there are a lot of reported issues like this but i now tried to follow this bug's suggestions:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-78860

"Alternatively, you can turn off IBus at System Settings | Language Support | Keyboard input method."

After I done this and a system restart, i never had the problem again.

Comment: This is now the real answer. Or an alternative workaround, from the same issue: `add "export IBUS_ENABLE_SYNC_MODE=1" to your ~/.profile, then restart a session.`

Answer (score 1):

Either upgrade IBus to version 1.5.11 or add `export IBUS_ENABLE_SYNC_MODE=1` to your ~/.profile, then restart a session.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-78860