# Stop keyboard becoming unresponsive on Pycharm startup

Tags: ssh, pycharm, x11, putty

## Symptoms:

When starting Pycharm:

- the keyboard seems completely unresponsive
- the cursor disappears
- menu items with keyboard bindings are greyed out
- text selection still works with the mouse, but the cursor is not visible

This may be related to another SO question ["pycharm with ideavim occasionally makes the keyboard unresponsive"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294884/pycharm-with-ideavim-occasionally-makes-the-keyboard-unresponsive) but ideavim is not involved.

## Set-up:

- remote desktop connection to a Windows 7 64-bit computer
- Windows machine has Xming running as a X-window server
- Using PuTTy to ssh tunnel into a Linux box running SuSE 11.3
- Pycharm v4.0.5
- JRE 1.7.0

## Further Details

- switching between tabs in Pycharm doesn't fix this
- no cursor is visible in the console, python, or editor windows
- switching to another X-window (xclock) doesn't help
- switching to another non-X-window doesn't help either
- re-starting Pycharm doesn't help
- `sudo ibus restart`, see [issue 78860](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-78860) on my flavor of linux doesn't do anything

Answer (score 2):

I am using pycharm in ubuntu and this thing worked for me. Just run this command in terminal. I don't even restarted. It worked.

```
$ ibus-daemon -rd
```

Answer (score 1):

## Working fix:

Turn off the 'Tip of the day' start-up dialogue box, then re-start Pycharm.

I can confirm that it works as a fix to my specific problem.

It sounds like there's a known problem with the cursor disappearing: see [issue 65637](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-65637) and [issue 79312](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-79312). Based on my experience it seems that this problem can also be caused when Pycharm pop-up windows steal focus.

Hope this is useful to some other folks out there.