# Keyboard not working in PyCharm IDE, cursor doesn't appear anywhere

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboard, pycharm

I recently download PyCharm Professional edition as a trial for 30 days. But this IDE doesn't seem to be working properly. The mouse works fine inside but the text cursor doesn't appear anywhere and the keyboard doesn't work inside PyCharm. The keyboard doesn't work anywhere. I have tried disabling Tip of The Day as suggested by another question on StackOverflow itself: [Stop keyboard becoming unresponsive on Pycharm startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29991007/stop-keyboard-becoming-unresponsive-on-pycharm-startup).
But the above question doesn't answer my problem properly. I need a solution to this problem as I have lots of editing to do immediately.

Comment: If you are on a GNU/Linux platform like Ubuntu or Debian and derivatives, try to install latest version of Ibus. If problem reappears restart Ibus. That is apparently a bug in Pycharm with Ibus.

Answer (score 7):

you can disable vim from tools->preference-> plugin. that worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I disable `IdeaVim` from `Preferences -> Plugins`,  search `IdeaVim` and disable the plugin should work. I did the same and it worked.